# Angular directive scope does/not pass to linking function

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a problem which seems completely crazy! I use a directive that takes some attributes bound to its scope, that take a value from a parent scope variable. All very normal.. 
...except when I do console.log(scope), the attributes are displayed normally as scope object's properties with the expected value, but when I do console.log(scope.myAttr) then I get undefined!!

Has anyone encountered something like this before??

```js
   // In parent directive:


scope.datepickerOptions.enableTime = false;




// In directive:

angular.module('myModule')
 .directive('datepicker', function() {
  return {
   require: 'ngModel',
   restrict : 'A',
   scope: {
    format: '@',
    enableTime: '=',
    minDate: '@',
    maxDate: '@',
    mode: '@'
   },
   link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    console.log("scope")
    console.log(scope)
    // displays all properties with expected values
                //=> scope.enableTime: false

    console.log("enableTime")
    console.log(scope.enableTime)
        // undefined (!!!)
        
        
        ...
```

```html
   // In parent template:

...

<input
  type="text"
  id="events_date"
  name="events_date"
  ng-model="events.selectedDate"
  placeholder="Select Date Range"
  ng-change="setQueryDate()"
  format="d M Y"
  mode="range"
  enable-time="datepickerOptions.enableTime"
  max-date="today"
  datepicker>
  
  
  ...
```

I also tried: 
enable-time="{{datepickerOptions.enableTime}}"  with enableTime: '@'

and I get the same craziness when I do 
console.log(attrs) and console.log(attrs.enableTime)

Same thing when I put a controller with $scope argument:
console.log($scope) displays everything normally, but console.log($scope.enableTime) gives   undefined

Comment: Try using 'attrs'. When the link function is executed, the scope properties aren't set yet. It gets set afterwards. That is why you get 'undefined' when you try to reference it directly. The scope object in your console displays the final state of the scope.

Comment: If you really need to use the 'scope' object, do it with the directive's controller function instead of the link function.

Comment: But won't the attrs.enableTime have "datepickerOptions.enableTime" as a value? And why all the other directives in the project function normally? Is it the **restrict: 'A'** that does this behaviour ?

Comment: Do you need a new scope without a controller?  Why not just scope: false so it is in the same scope as the variables already?

Comment: Can you once please try enable-time="true" in directive html and check whether its is getting logged in console

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias can you post your code in Plunker? I tried to replicate it your issue, but was unable to. The only thing I can think of is if the parent creates and sets enableTime after the directive is already created.

Comment: @SrinivasML when I do that with '@' in scope: {}  it works fine, but I need to be able to pass 'true' or 'false' via a variable, because I use the parent directive multiple times with different contexts

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias `console.log(scope)` will display all the properties if this properties were added/initialized later. In your case I think `console.log(angular.copy(scope));` will not show this properties. It is possible that the values are initialized in parent after the linking function was called.

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias its working for me , can you please check my plunker and let me know if I missed something https://plnkr.co/edit/jmnF4oAePOKyQAxSaqQT

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening is that you are setting enableTime after the directive is created. If that is the case you can use the 'ng-if' directive to check if it is defined first before loading it.

Here's an example of what I think is happening:

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.datepickerOptions = {}
  $timeout(function() {    
    $scope.datepickerOptions.enableTime = false;
  }, 500);
});
app.directive('datepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      enableTime: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      console.log("scope")
      console.log(scope)
        // displays all properties with expected values
        //=> scope.enableTime: false

      console.log("enableTime")
      console.log(scope.enableTime)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input datepicker ng-if="datepickerOptions.enableTime != null" enable-time="datepickerOptions.enableTime" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I finally solved the problem wrapping some scope.variables initialization inside a $timeout(), but it doesn't feel like a clean solution. I've never encountered this before, and the real question is why all the other directives I use, don't behave like that

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias It really depends on the code. For example, another fix for this is to initialize `$scope.datepickerOptions={ enableTime: true }` Without further information or examples, I don't think I would be able to answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any scope variables in your directive. If you want to keep any attribute value as `scope` variable, just do something like this:

```
scope.yourVariable = attrs.yourAttribute;
```

Comment: what do you mean? what is all this:
scope: {
    format: '@',
    enableTime: '=',
    minDate: '@',
    maxDate: '@',
    mode: '@'
   },

??

Comment: @DimitrisPapazacharias, it's just an instruction, but you didn't declare any **scope variable**. So you can get access to your attributes through `attrs` parameter like `attrs.neededAttribute`. Or, if you want to add this attribute to scope, you need to do `scope.yourVariable = attrs.neededAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if I do

```js
$timeout(function(){
  console.log(scope.enableTime)
}, 600)

//and in parent directive

$timeout(function(){
  scope.datepickerOptions.enableTime = true //or whatever
}, 500)
```

everything falls into place. But it doesn't seem to me like a clean solution. After all, I've never encountered something like this before, and how can anyone be sure when his/her directive will load and render??

Comment: You have to understand that JavaScript executes synchronously. I think the problem is that you don't have a full understanding on how JavaScript works. You probably want to research and try to understand how the timeouts works in JavaScript.